# Is there any way to make sure that downloaded file is from Microsoft?

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to make sure that the file which has been downloaded or is present on the system is from Microsoft and it hasn't been tampered with? If yes, any PowerShell way?

I am thinking of using the `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` commandlet but I am not sure if I am going in the right direction.

Can anyone please help me out on this?

Following is the output which I get for a file -

> PS C:> Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath .\sts2016-kb3141486-fullfile-x64-glb.exe | fl
>
> SignerCertificate      : [Subject]
>                              CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
>
> ```
>                     [Issuer]
>                        CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
>
>                     [Serial Number]
>                        330000014096A9EE7056FECC07000100000140
>
>                     [Not Before]
>                        8/18/2016 8:17:17 PM
>
>                     [Not After]
>                        11/2/2017 8:17:17 PM
>
>                     [Thumbprint]
>                        98ED99A67886D020C564923B7DF25E9AC019DF26
> ```
>
> TimeStamperCertificate :
>
> Status                 : Valid
>
> StatusMessage          : Signature verified.
>
> Path                   : C:\sts2016-kb3141486-fullfile-x64-glb.exe
>
> SignatureType          : Authenticode
>
> IsOSBinary             : False

So, if just check a file and it has got the same issuer and it's signature is verified, can I consider that file to be safe?

Thanks!

Comment: "Is there any way to make sure that the file which has been downloaded or is present on the system is from Microsoft and it hasn't been tampered with? If yes, any PowerShell way?" - Is there a reason what you have provided isn't acceptable?  The output it provides proves the file was signed by Microsoft and no changes to the file have been made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use checksums or as Microsoft calls them on their download page a Package hash.
This is a hash that can be created from the file. From the information page of the [software](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3141486/ms17-002-description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2016) that you provided, down towards the bottom is a section with File hash information.

[image]

You can use this information to confirm that you have downloaded the correct software.
PowerShell has a cmdlet called Get-FileHash that you run on the file. It defaults to using SHA256. You can use the -Algorithm parameter to use a different algorithm. I have used SHA1 in my example below as it matches the screen shot above. If you use -Algorithm SHA256, it matches the 'Package hash SHA 2' from the screen shot.

```
Get-FileHash C:\sts2016-kb3141486-fullfile-x64-glb.exe -Algorithm SHA1

Algorithm       Hash                                       Path                                                                                                                             
---------       ----                                       ----                                                                                                                             

SHA1            1B30B50FEB5FB3F8D764C6C0D6523DBA5BE05C1E   C:\sts2016-kb3141486-fullfile-x64-glb.exe
```

If the hashes match, you can be confident in your download.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: No worries. Happy I could help. :)